# Symfony2 PHPUnit functional test has x-debug-token header instead of X-Debug-Token

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm working on a Symfony 2.8.2 application.

Now, I want to check through the profiler if an email is sent successfully.
I enabled the profiler in my `config_test.yml` like that

```
framework:
    test: ~
    session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file
    profiler:
        enabled: true
        collect: false
```

So, I enable the profiler in my client and do the request in my phpunit functional test:

```
$client->enableProfiler();
$client->request($method, $path, $requestParameters, array(), $headers);
$mailCollector = $client->getProfile()->getCollector('swiftmailer');
```

But `$client->getProfile()` returns false.

I found the problem in the [Symfony Profiler](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Profiler/Profiler.php#L84) when at line 84 tries to get the token

```
if (!$token = $response->headers->get('X-Debug-Token')) {
     return false;
}
return $this->loadProfile($token);
```

I debugged my response and I found that has four headers and one of them is named 'x-debug-token'.

Why does my header have that name?
How I can modify that header to get the Profiler?

Thanks!

Comment: Headers are stored lowercased, but it doesn't matter when retrieving headers as they're always normalised. See https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/HeaderBag.php#L114 You seem to have done everything correctly, go through the http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/profiling.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/testing.html again. Perhaps there's a typo you made or have done something really specific in your project. Make sure the request you made was successful by checking the status code.

Comment: @JakubZalas I checked all the configurations. To send email with a phpunit functional test I'd to comment the entry "spool" in the swiftmailer config in the config.yml (It works only with that line commented, I tried file or memory option with no luck. I tried also to overwrite the value in config_test.yml). Now, I'm also able to get the request's token, but the profiler is still empty. It doesn't write data to /app/cache/profiler folder. I don't know why this is happening.